# SQLite - create table if not exists

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net

What is the create table statement in SQLite meant to return?

I have observed `create table if not exists` returning both a `0` and `1` when the table does in fact exist. Is the return value a reliable indication of whether the table does exist or not? I would expect the statement to return a `0` if the table already exists and a `1` when it does not, similar to an `insert` statement.

Comment: So you're using this as a method of determining whether a table exists?

Comment: In this library (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) it attempts to migrate the table if it does (using create table if not exists) however, the check for 0 sometimes fails because it will return 1 - even if the table does exist before executing the statement :/

Answer (score 2):

`Changes` returns the number of affected *rows*.
This values is meaningless for `CREATE TABLE` statements.

There is no easy way to determine whether the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` statement did the creation or not.
You should check beforehand with [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info).

Answer (score 1):

The `if not exists` syntax makes the command succeed even if the table already exists. It just doesn't do anything.

I'm not sure what you're referring to with "returns 1" unless you're talking about the command-line client. In that case, if you just remove the `if not exists` from your `create` statement, the command will return 1 (indicating failure) if the table exists.

Comment: Using the SQLite-NET library the command is executed using `ExecuteNonQuery` so it queries sqlite for the changes using `SQLite3.Changes(connectionHandle)`.